# Remove last Four Characters from the Dict key in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have below Dictionary

```
security_dict = {'F000000EU6XNAS' : ['23TEST1', 'ETEST'] , 'F000000EU6XNGS' : '23TEST2', 'F000000EU6' : '23TEST3'}
```

If the key length = 14 I would remove last 4 characters. Since there are lot of records I wanted to run the for loop. The o/p in above case would be

```
security_dict = {'F000000EU6' : ['23TEST1', 'ETEST'] , 'F000000EU6' : '23TEST2', 'F000000EU6' : '23TEST3'}
```

but since F000000EU6 is same will it be something like this

```
security_dict = {'F000000EU6' : ['23TEST1', 'ETEST', '23TEST2','23TEST3']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a new dict with keys of length 10.

```
security_dict = {'F000000EU6XNAS' : ['23TEST1', 'ETEST'] , 'F000000EU6XNGS' : '23TEST2', 'F000000EU6' : '23TEST3'}
new_security_dict = {}
new_key_length = 10
for key[:new_key_length] in security_dict.keys():
    if key in new_security_dict.keys():
        if type(security_dict[key]) == str:
            new_security_dict[key[:new_key_length]].append(security_dict[key])
        else:
            new_security_dict[key[:new_key_length]] = new_security_dict[key[:new_key_length]] + security_dict[key]
    else:
        if type(security_dict[key]) == str:
            new_security_dict[key[:new_key_length]] = [security_dict[key]]
        else:
            new_security_dict[key[:new_key_length]] = security_dict[key]
```

The `new_security_dict` should contain all keys of length `new_key_length`. If any key is less than or equal to `new_key_length` characters, then no characters are cut off of the key. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

when you trim last four character from the key, all the keys in your dict are same and dictionary doesn't allow duplicate keys in it.

Here is the code:

```
security_dict = {'F000000EU6XNAS' : ['23TEST1', 'ETEST'] , 'F000000EU6XNGS' : '23TEST2', 'F000000EU6' : '23TEST3'}
new_security_dict = {}

for key in security_dict.keys():
    if len(key) == 14:
        new_security_dict[key[:-4]] = security_dict[key]
    else:
        new_security_dict[key] = security_dict[key]
print(new_security_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'F000000EU6': '23TEST3'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, what you want to achieve is (a) shortening keys to a maximum length of 10 and (b) concatenating the values of shortened keys that collide (i.e. values of keys that result in the same key through shortening) into lists of strings. The values to be concatenated are either lists of strings themselves or otherwise simply strings.

To achieve this, I would do the following:

1. Create an intermediate dictionary of type [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), where the value for any key will default to an empty list (this will reduce necessary checks whether a shortened key already exists or not).
2. Create an entry for each shortened key in the intermediate dictionary, where I concatenate all values of the original dictionary that result in the same shortened key into a list.
3. *Optional:* Add a cleanup pass, where I extract the strings from all resulting 1-element lists. Otherwise, single strings will also form lists, which may or may not be fine, depending on your exact use case. If this step is omitted, I would probably still convert the `defaultdict` back into a standard `dict` to avoid unwanted side effects.

In code, this would look as follows:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

security_dict = {
    'F000000EU6XNAS' : ['23TEST1', 'ETEST'] ,
    'F000000EU6XNGS' : '23TEST2',
    'F000000EU6' : '23TEST3',
    # Add a non-colliding key that demonstrates the need for Step 3 below
    'DIFFERENTKEY' : 'TESTVAL'
}

# 1) New intermediate dict: missing keys will be an empty list
temp_dict = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in security_dict.items():
    # 2) Shorten keys, concatenate values of colliding keys
    #    (ensuring first that each value is a list)
    temp_dict[k[:10]] += [v] if isinstance(v, str) else v

# 3) Extract strings from resulting one-element lists
new_security_dict = {k: (v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v) for k, v in temp_dict.items()}

print(new_security_dict)
# >>> {'F000000EU6': ['23TEST1', 'ETEST', '23TEST2', '23TEST3'], 'DIFFERENTK': 'TESTVAL'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to ensure a consistent data structure.  Values that are sometimes lists and sometimes strings can only be a nightmare to process afterward.  Then you can use a simple update to consolidate the values on shorter keys:

```
secDict = {'F000000EU6XNAS' : ['23TEST1', 'ETEST'] ,
           'F000000EU6XNGS' : '23TEST2', 'F000000EU6' : '23TEST3'}

secDict.update( (k,[v]) for k,v in secDict.items() if not isinstance(v,list) )
secDict.update( (k[:10], secDict.get(k[:10],[])+ secDict.pop(k))
                for k in list(secDict) if len(k)==14)


print(secDict)                      
{'F000000EU6': ['23TEST3', '23TEST1', 'ETEST', '23TEST2']}
```